# Does it make sense to perform variance stablizing transform when a distribution is bimodal?

Tags: variance-stabilizing

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-stabilizing_transformation

The purpose of VST is "...such that the variability of the values y is not related to their mean value" according to Wikipedia.

But when a distribution is bimodal, the distribution is better characterized by the mean of each subpopulation, the variance of each subpopulation, and the proportion of the two subpopulations.

In this sense, VST is not applicable to data from bimodal distributions?

Is there something for bimodal distributions as VST for unimodal distributions?

Comment: "Related to their mean value" makes sense only when you understand "distribution" to mean a *family* of distributions.  What kind of bimodal family do you have in mind?  In some circumstances a VST would make sense but in others, as you suggest, it might have little utility.

Comment: I see some bimodal distribution which may be considered an overdispersed poison (I am not sure if it can be modeled as negative binomial or not) plus some outlines. The outliers are few, but they may be from distribution but just not very frequent. I am not sure what is the best way to deal with this case.

Comment: You appear to be examining a *single* distribution.  A variance-stabilizing transformation has no meaning in this context.  A transformation to *symmetrize* it might be meaningful, depending on your objective.  You really need to describe what your actual problem is.

Comment: No. It is a family of distribution. I am just saying for each one in the family what it looks like.

Comment: It is strange to be writing of "outliers" that are "not very frequent" when you really mean you are referring to a family of distributions.  That description is far from clear and needs further elaboration.

Comment: Think of this way, for example, I have a family of NBs mixed with another extremely dispersed NBs, the dispersed NBs are very infrequent so that the majority of the data looks like the first NBs, the rest looks like outliers. But this is just an example. My original question is still when VST makes sense for bimodal distributions, when it does not. The answer is better a necessary-sufficient condidtion.

Comment: You appear to speak interchangeably of *data* and *distributions* and *families of distributions.*  This doesn't work, because they aren't equivalent.  One way--probably the best way--to attract good answers is to edit your question to clarify and motivate it.

Comment: I don't think my explanation is not clear. The data are from the NB mixed distribution in the example.